# Estimating values with which to replace NA

Tags: r, statistics, plyr, lm

I have a data set that consists of several timeseries for which I want to calculate estimates within those timeseries to replace NA values.   I am familiar with ddply() and lm() but I am having a bit of trouble with this one....

Here are the first 5 stations from one dataframe

```
x <- read.table( text="
LOC     YEAR    JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
A       1980    0   0   0   8   104 NA  534 399 202 20  0   0
A       1981    0   0   0   45  121 387 454 309 135 29  0   0
A       1982    0   0   6   25  123 346 459 423 223 11  0   0
A       1983    0   0   0   20  88  294 474 424 296 38  3   0
A       1984    0   0   0   28  192 340 385 339 122 3   0   0
A       1985    0   0   12  40  142 327 407 445 198 13  0   0
A       1986    0   0   0   59  147 290 381 362 176 10  0   0
A       1987    0   0   0   12  83  288 408 395 112 12  0   0
A       1988    0   0   0   8   116 309 393 392 152 11  2   0
A       1989    0   0   7   69  238 366 442 402 158 23  0   0
A       1990    0   1   0   38  186 527 397 298 225 11  0   0
A       1991    0   0   5   15  201 378 374 364 137 25  0   0
A       1992    0   0   0   31  96  284 457 381 212 28  0   0
A       1993    0   0   0   40  149 400 510 425 174 24  0   0
A       1994    0   0   12  37  172 502 524 474 209 49  5   0
A       1995    0   0   14  21  157 340 447 457 220 8   0   0
A       1996    0   3   0   36  361 457 482 378 160 46  0   0
A       1997    0   0   3   19  141 357 481 429 272 51  0   0
A       1998    0   0   9   6   197 438 553 396 323 60  0   0
A       1999    0   0   0   22  147 323 456 465 215 18  0   0
A       2000    0   0   0   53  305 387 503 436 278 53  0   0
A       2001    0   0   0   27  212 416 553 432 246 23  2   0
A       2002    0   0   3   63  192 483 469 499 224 37  1   0
A       2003    0   0   0   32  NA  357 494 480 NA  54  22  0
A       2004    0   0   19  18  222 358 398 318 146 15  0   0
A       2005    0   0   0   4   157 376 472 376 287 46  1   0
A       2006    0   0   5   64  269 435 496 NA  107 29  1   0
A       2007    0   0   3   6   87  336 396 444 264 83  0   0
A       2008    0   0   2   11  181 487 417 399 130 26  0   0
A       2009    0   2   0   32  189 394 509 441 174 50  0   0
A       2010    0   0   4   32  154 490 401 465 299 21  0   0
B       1980    0   0   0   6   108 530 581 411 199 10  0   0
B       1981    0   0   0   55  101 412 451 330 149 25  0   0
B       1982    0   0   6   26  116 346 502 483 244 10  0   0
B       1983    0   0   0   11  93  295 514 488 320 40  0   0
B       1984    0   0   0   31  200 334 402 347 NA  8   0   0
B       1985    0   0   9   40  151 318 431 456 209 16  0   0
B       1986    0   0   3   59  150 298 409 410 179 8   0   0
B       1987    0   0   NA  13  87  315 456 403 137 12  0   0
B       1988    0   0   0   12  NA  327 303 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
B       1989    NA  0   NA  62  248 366 445 443 187 22  0   0
B       1990    0   0   1   31  171 568 439 321 248 16  0   0
B       1991    0   0   3   27  227 368 361 361 143 15  0   0
B       1992    0   0   0   34  75  268 432 395 224 9   0   0
B       1993    0   NA  0   28  144 411 519 421 169 16  0   0
B       1994    0   0   4   25  139 484 520 485 210 NA  NA  NA
B       1995    NA  NA  7   NA  146 NA  NA  491 219 NA  0   NA
B       1996    NA  NA  0   NA  NA  440 507 NA  NA  50  NA  NA
B       1997    NA  NA  NA  2   NA  266 483 412 252 43  0   0
B       1998    0   0   5   9   208 430 558 417 354 66  0   0
B       1999    NA  0   0   24  111 303 NA  432 206 29  0   0
B       2000    0   0   0   72  338 417 553 468 300 47  0   0
B       2001    NA  0   1   38  215 459 626 481 250 37  6   0
B       2002    0   0   13  84  208 433 528 525 NA  NA  3   0
B       2003    0   0   2   48  220 385 580 483 257 61  12  NA
B       2004    0   0   16  22  231 372 413 352 199 11  0   NA
B       2005    NA  0   0   13  167 NA  529 400 288 49  0   0
B       2006    0   0   6   89  279 459 535 403 100 31  0   0
B       2007    0   0   4   27  68  338 406 452 293 87  0   0
B       2008    0   0   0   31  188 503 439 399 107 28  0   0
B       2009    0   0   NA  21  162 394 468 387 138 33  0   0
B       2010    0   0   0   17  134 439 NA  429 210 13  0   0
C       1987    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   0
C       1988    0   0   3   19  228 382 435 422 213 17  16  0
C       1989    0   1   17  100 332 432 543 459 208 66  0   0
C       1990    0   0   2   54  243 615 414 318 255 27  2   0
C       1991    0   0   2   41  304 539 505 513 NA  100 0   0
C       1992    0   0   0   83  157 368 531 452 300 67  0   0
C       1993    0   0   2   79  211 448 572 498 215 75  0   0
C       1994    1   0   21  46  194 580 618 541 257 66  7   0
C       1995    0   0   36  54  224 437 551 532 273 31  2   0
C       1996    0   7   1   70  436 511 550 432 216 62  1   0
C       1997    0   0   11  27  177 412 556 501 336 74  0   0
C       1998    0   0   21  25  308 572 638 475 407 87  0   0
C       1999    0   1   3   58  218 417 536 542 288 55  0   0
C       2000    0   0   0   110 396 446 610 540 380 80  0   0
C       2001    0   0   3   67  290 533 648 533 335 72  12  0
C       2002    0   0   9   161 296 563 534 597 297 62  3   0
C       2003    0   0   3   91  249 435 571 566 NA  100 29  0
C       2004    0   0   26  49  308 416 467 391 212 24  0   0
C       2005    0   0   0   22  197 468 557 NA  355 70  1   0
C       2006    0   0   13  117 NA  488 557 NA  141 36  6   0
C       2007    0   0   6   22  113 376 445 463 292 98  0   0
C       2008    0   0   NA  41  240 554 443 430 NA  57  2   0
C       2009    0   NA  13  62  252 480 530 478 216 61  0   0
C       2010    0   0   1   32  212 525 399 489 309 34  0   0
D       2007    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  285 NA  213 34  0   NA
D       2008    0   0   0   11  121 NA  301 275 85  29  0   0
D       2009    0   NA  1   23  103 346 NA  389 106 29  0   0
D       2010    0   0   4   6   96  435 323 367 255 14  0   0
E       1980    0   0   2   36  188 583 654 503 279 52  0   0
E       1981    0   0   4   58  NA  455 NA  NA  226 NA  1   1
E       1982    0   3   25  NA  NA  445 553 552 357 49  0   NA
E       1983    0   0   0   58  202 397 549 534 384 90  7   0
E       1984    0   0   3   65  278 407 453 447 226 29  3   0
E       1985    0   0   21  82  237 384 492 534 278 NA  NA  0
E       1986    0   6   7   109 219 354 466 458 258 NA  NA  0
E       1987    0   0   0   42  142 344 475 475 195 56  4   NA
E       1988    0   0   1   23  209 NA  NA  458 247 39  13  0
E       1989    0   3   34  131 314 459 539 478 241 79  0   0
E       1990    0   1   6   74  268 618 444 359 294 43  10  0
E       1991    0   0   15  57  285 439 434 445 193 81  0   0
E       1992    0   0   1   70  143 424 547 473 297 55  0   0
E       1993    0   0   0   67  187 413 582 440 271 103 0   0
E       1994    0   0   10  66  239 585 592 556 284 67  9   0
E       1995    0   0   17  56  205 413 546 531 293 51  0   0
E       1996    0   9   0   73  412 550 580 476 250 88  3   0
E       1997    0   0   14  37  198 433 574 502 369 90  0   0
E       1998    0   0   21  11  332 542 664 473 423 91  0   0
E       1999    0   0   2   94  231 435 562 571 313 63  0   0
E       2000    0   0   9   139 419 437 601 534 361 76  0   0
E       2001    0   0   2   64  285 493 629 521 308 40  10  0
E       2002    0   0   13  131 277 528 524 549 281 72  3   0
E       2003    0   0   3   90  250 420 523 520 NA  86  21  0
E       2004    0   0   35  35  NA  404 470 384 215 34  0   0
E       2005    0   0   0   26  198 452 544 441 391 87  3   0
E       2006    0   0   8   123 NA  489 573 NA  194 74  5   0
E       2007    0   0   12  18  121 389 450 524 346 134 0   0
E       2008    0   0   8   49  239 596 501 488 213 48  0   0
E       2009    0   NA  4   38  260 487 534 499 223 77  0   0
E       2010    0   0   7   36  212 564 454 533 367 38  0   0

 ", header = T)
```

Here goes...

I need to remove any location with less than 7 years data, the entire data set has a couple hundred locations...

then

Replace any NA with the correct monthly locational mean

I am trying to calculate the monthly mean of individual stations and place them NA's associated with that station month

I am stuck here...

```
xFix <- melt(x, id.vars = c("LOC", "YEAR"), measure.vars = c("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"), variable.name = "Month", value.name = "CLDD")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Thank you so much.
Jesse

Answer (score 0):

FROM SE

Here's a proposal.

Firstly, count the number of rows for each LOC and check whether there are seven or more rows. This is used for subsetting x.

```
cnt <- table(x$LOC) >= 7
```

Then cnt is used for removing LOCs with an insufficient number of rows. This creates a new data frame tmp.

```
tmp <- x[x$LOC %in% names(cnt)[cnt], ]
```

The next command is quite complex. by is used to apply the function to each subset of the data frame along the values of LOC. Since only the month columns are of interest, only these columns are selected using month.abb. The command lapply is used to apply the following function to each column of the subset of the data frame: Replace all NAs with the mean of the column.

The functions as.data.frame and do.call(rbind, ...) are necessary to obtain a data frame.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(tmp[, toupper(month.abb)], 
                     tmp$LOC[drop = TRUE], 
                     FUN = function(y) 
                        as.data.frame(lapply(y, function(z)
                                       replace(z, is.na(z), mean(z, na.rm = TRUE))))))
```

In the last step, the first two columns are combined with the result.

```
cbind(tmp[c("LOC", "YEAR")], res)
```

Done.